# OCSP validation without issuer certificate

Tags: validation, certificate, ocsp

I am currently developing an application that validates signature certificates (like in a pdf) with OCSP or CRL. These will most likely be leaf certificates, without the entire chain. Getting the url to either validation services proved simple enough.

To my understanding, both OCSP and CRL require the issuer of the certificate to validate it. So now I'm stuck because that is not included in the input. The AIA extension might include a URL to a CA certificate, but unfortunately this is the CA of the issuing certificate and not the certificate itself.

Is there any other way to get the issuer's certificate given only the leaf? Or are there some cases in which OCSP/CRL can validate without it?

Comment: did you happen to figure out a workaround to this? I'm in the exact same position and was wondering if there are any alternatives

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt`  which details the requirements for an OCSP response to be considered valid:

> The key
>     used to sign the response MUST belong to one of the following:
>
> -- the CA who issued the certificate in question
>
> -- a Trusted Responder whose public key is trusted by the requester
>
> -- a CA Designated Responder (Authorized Responder) who holds a
>        specially marked certificate issued directly by the CA, indicating
>        that the responder may issue OCSP responses for that CA

The first and third option both require the issuer cert. The second option does not. However I dont think that option is applicable to you situation. The link https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:OCSP-TrustedResponder has details on what a trusted responder is and when it can actually be used.